# How to omit nested object property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

what would be the best method to remove `notneeded` property from this array?

```
function apiCall(...args) {
  //at this point I need to remove 'notneeded' property from args
};

apiCall({a: 'one', b: 'two'}, {notneeded: '', c: 'three'}, 'hello');
```

Those passed objects could be primitives, functions etc., so ideally the solution would handle every case.

I have created following function for this problem but I am sure there is a better solution (possibly with new ECMA standards).

```
function omit(args, omitKey) {
  let omitted = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (typeof args[i] === 'object') {
      omitted.push(
        Object.keys(args[i]).reduce((result, key) => {
          if (key !== omitKey) {
            result[key] = args[i][key];
          }
          return result;
        }, {}),
      );
    } else {
      omitted.push(args[i]);
    }
  }
  return omitted;
}
```

Comment: Is it "notneeded" or "activelyharmful"?

Comment: @Bergi well, in this particular case its later on passed as part of backend request and causes exception, so yeah, you could call it "activelyharmful" :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Find its index and splice it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix the array iteration into that method. Make it do one task only.

```
function omit(obj, keyToOmit) {
    if (typeof obj != "object") return obj;
    const result = {};
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (key != keyToOmit) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function apiCall(...args) {
    args = args.map(arg => omit(arg, "notneeded"));
    …
}
```